# Scrolling Stops working when bootstrap modal is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I using Bootstrap v3.1.1 to display modal popup to one of my web page. Below is the way I have added it.

```
<!--Start  show add student popup here -->
<div class="modal fade" id="add-student" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div id="divStudentPopUp"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--End  show add student popup here -->

<!-- JS Code Goes Here -->
//--- Add Student POP Up Script-- Start
$('#add-student').modal('toggle');
$('#add-student').modal('show');
$('#add-student').modal('hide');
//--- Add Student POP Up Script-- End
<!-- END -->
```

I am adding the textual content dynamically from a AJAX call when the modal popup is opened. I have two button on it SAVE and CANCEL.

```
<!-- HTML for Cancel button -->
<button class="hvr-ripple-out btn btn-red cancel" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnCancelStudent">Cancel</button>
```

The Problem here is when I hit the CANCEL button the modal gets closed but the parent window (body) scroll is not working.

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Can you provide fiddle of the same ?

Comment: you are triggering the modal instance more then once with `toggle` and `show` remove `toggle` and also remove `hide` instance too because you are closing the modal with `data-dismiss="modal"` so don't need `hide`

Comment: I have already tried this. It doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Check if your body has class 'model-open', this class add properties overflow-y:hidden, just remove this class on model close

```
$('#add-student').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a common problem, add a call back function.

```
$('add-student').removeClass('modal-open');
```

Comment: You have a typo, you need '#' before the id: `$('#add-student')`

Answer (score 0):

check this fiddle here i have just typed some contents to show the page scroll
http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/0fscmf3L/

```
   <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
      Close
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
      Save changes
    </button>
  </div>
```

If any problem persists please upload your code to fiddle and share I'll check.